# RECOVER code returns 51 jpegs and are incorrect i need some cues

Tags: c, cs50

So I'm trying CS50 Recover exercise (where you need to search for jpg files in a memory card and whenever you find one- you open a new file and write the jpg found to the new file). My code compiles and returns 51 jpegs instead of only 50 and all of them are incorrect. Please, I need some cues on what to focus at and fix/replace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     // Check for valid usage
    if ( argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Check for valid image
    FILE *image = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (image == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }


        BYTE buffer[512];
        int i = 0;
        char new_image[8];
        FILE *output;
        FILE *output1;
        while (fread (buffer, 1, 512, image) == 512)
        {


            // IF Start of a JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
        {
            sprintf(new_image, "%03i.jpg", i);
          //if  first JPEG
                if ( i == 0)
               {
                    output = fopen(new_image, "w");
                 fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, output);
                 i++;
               }
         // if not first JPEG
                else
               {
               fclose(output);
               sprintf(new_image, "%03i.jpg", i);
               output1 = fopen(new_image, "w");
               fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, output1);
               fclose(output1);
               i++;
               }
        }
        // if not start of a JPEG
        else
        {
            output = output1 = fopen(new_image, "w");
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, output);

        }

        }
        fclose(image);

}
```

Comment: The **only** difference between the first image and every other image is that you don't need to close the old file before starting the new file. And you only need one file pointer, not two. And there should be exactly one `fopen` in the code, not three (not counting the `fopen` for the input file).